# Combine columns in different rows in dataframe python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to join columns in different rows in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

tdf =  {'ph1': [1, 2], 'ph2': [3, 4], 'ph3': [5,6], 'ph4': [nan,nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=tdf)

df
```

Output:

```
   ph1  ph2  ph3  ph4

0    1    3    5  nan

1    2    4    6  nan
```

I combined ph1, ph2, ph3, ph4 with below code:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():

        df = df[[ph1, ph2, ph3, ph4]]

        df["ConcatedPhoneNumbers"] = df.loc[0:].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x), axis=1)
```

I got

```
df["ConcatPhoneNumbers"]

ConcatPhoneNumbers

1,3,5,,

2,4,6,,
```

Now I need to combine these columns using pandas with appropriate function. 
My result should be `1,3,5,2,4,6`

Also need to remove these extra commas.

I am new Python learner.I did some research and reached till here. Please help me to get the exact approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove `NaN`s, then convert to `int`, `str` and `list` and last `join`:

```
tdf =  {'ph1': [1, 2], 'ph2': [3, 4], 'ph3': [5,6], 'ph4': [np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=tdf)

cols = ['ph1', 'ph2', 'ph3', 'ph4']
s = ','.join(df[cols].stack().astype(int).astype(str).values.tolist())
print (s)
1,3,5,2,4,6
```

Comment: Thanks alot for responding.Not really. I need to combine these concatenated numbers. I actually need 1,3,5,2,4,6. I will drop the 2nd row once these all are combined.

Comment: But not sure if understand - is possible add more data to sample for better explanation?

Comment: Data actually contains phone numbers containing 10 digits. Data is like:    tdf = {'ph1': [118-975-8368, 118-975-8369], 'ph2': [118-240-6465, 118-240-6469], 'ph3': ['nan', 'nan'], 'ph4': ['nan','nan']}. I need 118-975-8368, 118-975-8369,118-240-6465, 118-240-6469 as my output.

Comment: It doesn't work.Giving ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '118-975-8368'

Comment: I even tried tdf[pd.to_numeric(tdf['ph1'], errors='coerce').isnull()]             
from one of your previous answers. Still getting the same Value error.

Comment: Sorry, only omit `.astype(int).astype(str)`, so need `s = ','.join(df[cols].stack().values.tolist())
print (s)`

Comment: ','.join(tdf.loc[1:, 'ConcatNumbers'].astype(str).values.tolist()) This worked for me.